# PHP how to retrieve a string inbetween 2 characters?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm having trouble with this, I did find a couple of reg ex examples but I can't seem to get them to work for me.

```
$string = '1. A post-hardcore band from Brazil 2. A rock band from Sweden';
```

I need to retrieve everything inbetween the "1." and "2."

Is there some kind of simple splitting function in PHP that I could use like so?

```
$result = string_between_chars($string, "1. ", "2 .");
```

Or, if I'm matching for numbers

```
preg_match('~(1.|2.|3.|4.)~', ($string), $matches
```

Is there anyway I could modify this to be left with the result of

```
[0] => 1. A post-hardcore band from Brazil
[1] => 2. A rock band from Sweden
```

Comment: Please show the code of what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a solution:

```
<?php
function string_between_chars($string, $from, $to){
  preg_match("/$from(.*)$to/",$string,$match);
  return $match[1];
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$result = string_between_chars($string, '1\. ', '2\. ');
```

Add a backslash before dots. Dots has special meaning in regular expressions. You can escape it with the backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately nothing is being returned using this.

Comment: Ehh. the result is in the $match[1]. I modify the answer to be a real function.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works:

```
/\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|$)/
```

**In PHP:**

```
$str = '1. A post-hardcore band from Brazil 2. A rock band from Sweden' 
         .'3. A rock band from Hawaii 4. A metal band from Germany';
preg_match_all('/\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|$)/',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1. A post-hardcore band from Brazil 
            [1] => 2. A rock band from Sweden
            [2] => 3. A rock band from Hawaii 
            [3] => 4. A metal band from Germany
        )
)
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb390e0a9f5dc69e59b49b482423bbaee8561719)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply use this regex as long as no digits in the sentences:

```
(\d\.\s*[^\d]+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eE0iK5)

But if digits are in the sentences, check @OGHaza's solution instead :)

Comment: matching `\s*` is unnecessary, which leaves you with exactly my regex.

Comment: Yes undeed, just in case there's multiple spaces.. who knows :)

Comment: Yes but it makes literally no difference to the matches.
`.` matches whitespace, so `\s*.*? = .*?` 
And it is the last thing in the lookahead and the `*` means match whether or not theres whitespace. So it makes 0 difference to any matches.

Comment: Oh damn, I see your point, you're totally right....